# Get notifications in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to get notifications from other applications in android ? Like if the user is going to longpress on something in any explorer at that time can i get notification in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Android has [Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) An application can notify other application of some action using sending broadcast.